# D3 data binding (two dimensional array)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to achieve such behaviour by using `d3.js` `.data()` binding function?

```
d3.selectAll('.rects')
  .data([[1,2,3],[a,b,c],[x,y,z])
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', ([number, character, character]) => { /* 1, a, x */ });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [d3.zip](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#zip)

```js
var data = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]; 
var zippedData = d3.zip.apply(null, data);
console.log(zippedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```